# Determine types of edges using networkx

Tags: python, networkx

Is there a built in function in networkx to tell me the type of edges I have in my directed graph using BFS?

If not, does anyone have any good strategies for identifying the forward, backward, and cross edges in a BFS?

Thanks

MORE INFORMATION

```
 a = [(0,1), (2,1), (1,2), (0,3), (3,2)]
 G = nx.DiGraph(a)
 bfs = nx.breath_first_search.bfs_tree(G, source=3)
 # ISSUE identify the edge types for each edge from source 3
```

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, can you provide an input and expected output.

Comment: sure thing, give me a couple.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @AChampion i need to label, back forward edges, etc..